# Ajuste do button bootstrap css

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-3, formulário

Estou tentando acertar a altura de um `button` no formulário, mas ele aparece muito alto em relação aos campos:
[image: imagem do formulario]

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
<div class="col-lg-2">
  <label class="form-group">Categoria:
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="cat">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
  <label class="form-group">Valor: 
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="valor">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
  <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Gravar</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: tente postar o código todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, você está não está usando Bootstrap corretamente.

As classes de coluna, `class="col-{xs, sm, md, lg}-{1-12}`, em princípio deveriam ser usadas dentro de linhas, `class="row"`, mas esse isso é o de menos.

A ideia do Bootstrap é criar um *framework* responsivo com foco na ideia de ***mobile first***, ou seja, a ideia central é que você pense em aparelhos móveis primeiro, desta forma, a classe `col-xs-*` quer dizer ***eXtra Small*** (extra pequeno), se referindo à tela. `col-sm-*` quer dizer ***small*** (pequeno). `col-md-*`, ***medium*** (médio). `col-lg-*`, ***large*** (grande). Bem, mas isso se você não estiver pensando somente em dar suporte aos *desktop*.

Outra coisa é, os botões, incluindo os input tipo button e submit, têm suas próprias classes e `form-control` não é uma delas.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
        <label class="form-group">Categoria: <input class="form-control" type="text" name="cat"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
        <label class="form-group">Valor: <input class="form-control input-md" type="text" name="valor"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i> Gravar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/TonnyMontana/foeL961z/)

Answer (score 1):

Isso está acontecendo porque o botão está sem `label`, coloque alguma que já vai resolver o problema:

Clique em **Executar** e depois em **Página Toda** para ver como vai ficar na visualização que você postou na imagem.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
<form>
<div class="col-lg-2">
  <label class="form-group">Categoria: 
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="cat">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
  <label class="form-group">Valor: 
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="valor">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
  <label class="form-group">Gravar 
    <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i> Gravar</button>
  </label>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sua resposta não está correta. Botões não precisam de *label*, se precisassem seriam *self-closing tags* como os *input*. O que acontece é que ele colocou a classe `form-control`, usada em `input` no `button`.

Comment: Obrigado, Tony Montana. O form-control no button, foi uma tentativa estúpida para acertar o alinhamento do objeto. Colocar o label no button, também não resolve. Eu desenvolvo aplicativos para web, claro que a questão de ser responsivo é importante, mas a principio os forms serão utiiizados em pcs.